# Load jinja2 templates dynamically on a Pyramid view

Tags: jinja2, pyramid

I'm developing a [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) project with [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) templating engine. Following  the [jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/) I've find out a way to load different templates from a unique view. But taking into account that the module [pyramid_jinja2](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-jinja2/en/latest/) was already configured in my app with a default path for templates.  I was wondering if there is another way more elegant to get this done. This is my approach:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

@view_config(context=Test)
def test_view(request):
    env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('project_name', 'templates'))
    template = env.get_template('section1/example1.jinja2')
    return Response(template.render(data={'a':1,'b':2}))
```

Can I get an instance of the **pyramid_jinja2** environment from somewhere so I don't have to set again the default path for templates in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is enough:

```
  from pyramid.renderers import render

  template = "section/example1.jinja2"
  context = dict(a=1, b=2)
  body = render(template, context, request=request)
```

And to configure loading do in your `__init__.py`:

```
  config.add_jinja2_search_path('project_name:templates', name='.jinja2', prepend=True)
```

Comment: I did as you said and seems to work fine, but when I've tried to use internationalized text in the template, it breaks. For example {{ gettext('NAME') }}  throws the following error: **return request.localizer** -  **AttributeError**: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'localizer'

Comment: Apparently `request` needs some special handling for gettext. I suggest you open another question for this with full traceback "How to use gettext with pyramid_jinja2"